# How to plug in a Philips Low Pressure Sodium Bulb using a Ballast

Tags: electrical, lighting

I bought these 3 things on Amazon: 
 
•   Leviton 8806 Bayonet Base, Keyless, HID, Glazed Porcelain Lampholder 
•   Fulham WH2-120-C Workhorse Adaptable Ballast
•   Philips 327817 35-watt T15 SOX35 Low Pressure Sodium HID Light Bulb

[image: PICTURE]

[image: PICTURE]

I don’t know a ton about electricity or LPS bulbs but I need to safely plug this in to a regular 110V wall outlet. I’m not sure what the job of the ballast is, but I’m guessing I have to wire it into a power cable that will then plug into the wall. Am I right?

And do the 2 white cables from the Lampholder connect to the Black & White cable on the ballast?

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Take a close-up pic of the label on the ballast, I tried to zoom it, but can't read it blown up that much.

Comment: Also, you need an enclosure for that lamp. Do NOT burn it without, it's unsafe, if the bulb explodes you'll know why I warned you.

Comment: Also googling the part number that ballast appears to be fluorescent.  Why do you think it pairs to that lamp?

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Tyson, I bought that Balast because that's the one AMAZON recommended, it's model is WH2-120-C. 

Can you recommend an enclosure?

Comment: I can't tonight because I'm out of time, I'll look up the ballast wiring diagram tomorrow if someone doesn't do it overnight.   Also actually I just noticed your low pressure sodium bulb might not be as explosive as HPS or High Preasure Sodium, I don't have facts there.  Any particular reason you didn't just buy a whole fixture?  Bulb, ballast and enclosure pre-wired.

Comment: had no idea where to buy that. and I looked for many many months

Comment: Not sure what your application is, if it's for security search "HPS wallpack", if it's for your indoor hydroponic tomato garden type "HPS grow light" (both searches at Amazon work). I don't know much about your choice of a low pressure sodium bulb, but I'm guessing you don't either and sodium was the keyword.  If that's the case go with HPS it appears to be more efficient.  My recommendation is that you return those items to Amazon and buy a complete fixture.

Comment: Amazon recommendations **are absolutely NOT** about compatibility.  They are used for marketing, and shows things their algorithm thinks you are most likely to buy given what it knows about you, or that their advertisers have paid them to promote.

Answer (score 3):

I bought the same stuff. At first it appeared to be the wrong ballast. Of course it came without any guidance.

I tried it and it does work.

Black & white wires to to 120VAC power.
Red wires (2) tie together and connect to one of the lamp socket wires.
Yellow wire goes to the other lamp socket wire.

When you apply power the lamp will glow immediately but not very brightly. The light
will be orangeish not yellow. Let it warm up for a few minutes maybe 5-10 and it will be bright yellow like you would expect.

I have run the lamp once and it works. I cannot comment on whether it is correct or safe. The current consumption was low and everything seemed well behaved.

Proceed at your own risk.

Answer (score 2):

### This is a bunch of random junk.

Stop buying things this way.  You can't just throw random electronic bits together and have them work.  But don't feel bad, this happens a **lot**. We get a steady stream of people buying random dimmers and smart switches and wanting to configure them 3-way to control some cheap LEDs they got off the bottom shelf of Walmart, or other equally random things.

### School up

You just need to get some magazines, good "how I built it" sites on the Internet, or whatever, and read up on how others are doing what you are trying to do.   By the way, low pressure sodium is the best for some applications.

### Buy used

From time to time, low-pressure sodium fixtures come up on the used market: Craigslist, eBay, etc.  See what you can find. Good chance though if you are trying to do home herb farming, the best lamps may be in high demand, especially now that many states have made one particular herb legal.

Answer (score -1):

This ballast will run a 18W SOX bulb fantastic and would more than likely run the 35w fine also. A compact fluorescent ballast with correct wattage rating can safely run these low wattage low pressure sodium bulbs great.

Answer (score -1):

The WH2 ballast divides its output between the two red leads and uses the yellow as a commom. Connecting the two red leads together will deliver the full output to the lamp.
The SOX-e lamps can be driven by various arc tube supplies , however since the current density of the arc and the arc voltage of LPS lamps is a narrow optimum band and is different from the design characteristics of mercury vapor HID and fluorescent tubes the light output is below the designed optimum output.  When possible it is still better to drive the lamps with a lamp specific power supply.
Philips - 71A0201|LPS 18W Ballast  w/o the cap.  $55.00 ea + $10 shipping ,
https://topbulb.com/philips-71a0201lps-18w-ballast ,
They have 3 left in stock ,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/160073)